# How can I make a function run automatically in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a dynamic html page with JavaScript and I want to run a function   automatically without using `onclick` and I want to execute it with a delay.

I tried `setTimeout()` but it didn't work as expected.

How can I convert the code below to run `function updateSliderValue()` automatically with delay but without button?

```
<!--creating a container for the input box--> 
<div><button onclick="updateSliderValue();">Set value</button></div>
```

the code is:

```
    }
         function updateSliderValue() {
            slider = widget.getByName("Slider1");
            slider.setValue();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="clear: both; margin-top: 40px;"></div>
<div class="cell">
        <div class="container" style="height: 100px;">
            <div class="widget" style="height: 100%;" id="root">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--creating a container for the input box--> 
    <div><button onclick="updateSliderValue();">Set value</button></div> 


</body>
</html>
```

thank you so much for your effort and your time but i don't know where put the code you gave to me.

Comment: should it run when the page is loaded?

Comment: "I tried setTimeout() but it didn't work as expected." — Well, that is the tool to use. We can't tell why your attempt to use it didn't work as expected because (a) you haven't shown us your attempt and (b) you haven't told us how the behaviour you got differed from what you expected.

Comment: @Quentin - the _expected_ was one of my contributions to the edit. He just said "setTimout did not work" - same effect though :)

Comment: i updated the post can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function updateSliderValue() {
  //work
}

(function() {
  setTimeout(updateSliderValue,1000);
})();
```

or **when the page has to be loaded then below**

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(updateSliderValue,1000);
});
```

Comment: Note: the first code will start the timeout immediately the code is run. The second will wait until page load

Comment: yes, just wanted to give him both options. he did not mention anything about page load, but yes, i should mention it in my answer

Comment: thank you so much for your effort and your time but i don't know where put the code you gave to me.

Comment: just below updateSliderValue function in your code, you can add $(function() {
    setTimeout(updateSliderValue,1000);
});

Comment: i put like this but no result:    
  `}
   function updateSliderValue() {
   slider = widget.getByName("Slider1");
            slider.setValue();
  }
  $(function() { setTimeout(updateSliderValue,500); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="clear: both; margin-top: 40px;"></div>
<div class="cell">
        <div class="container" style="height: 100px;">
            <div class="widget" style="height: 100%;" id="root">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- --> 
 <div><button onclick="updateSliderValue();">Set value</button></div> 
</body>
</html>`

Comment: finally work but i used setInterval() instead setTimeout() thank you soooooooo much Oxi.

Answer (score 0):

To run code on page load, you can use the window.onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  updateSliderFunction();
};
```

Or you can use $(document).ready for jquery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateSliderFunction();
});
```